# Add a Key to an Array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm battling to understand how to resolve the warning:

> `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined`
>   being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child
>   component, you should pass it as a different prop.

I have added 'i' in my map function, and passing it to my child as 'key'.

I'm not sure what it means by 'pass it as a different prop'. What am I doing wrong?

```
 {   
          this.state.accounts.map(function(account, i){
              return (
                  <AccountCard 
                         key={i}
                         lastTransactions = {account.lastTransactions} 
                         bank={account.bank} 
                         number={account.number} 
                         id={account.id} 
                   />         
             )
       })
    }
```

In the AccountCard component, I access the key/id like this:

```
 <div className=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" key={this.props.key}>
```

Comment: are you trying to access the key inside `AccountCard` component?

Comment: just a pointer, `key` should be unique. Just adding a number is a bad idea. It can create conflict.

Comment: try `key={account.id}` and let me know what happens.

Comment: I added how I am using the id in the component to the question.

Comment: You're accessing `this.props.key` which is for React itselft - don't do it. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not in this snippet (altough the use of index as key is not recommended, use `account.id` as key), but in the `AccountCard` component declaration. I think there you're trying to do something like `props.key`.

If you really need that `i` in the child component, add another props just for that and use that in the child.

```
<AccountCard 
   key={account.id}
   i={i}
   lastTransactions = {account.lastTransactions} 
   bank={account.bank} 
   number={account.number} 
   id={account.id} 
/>     


<div className=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" key={this.props.i}>
```

Comment: I've added where I use the key to the question. You might be onto something.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Ursus. I don't really need 'i' at all. I'm just hoping to be rid of the warning. So, just having 'key={account.id}' should be enough? I can get rid of id={account.id} and i={i} as well as the i in the "function(account, i)"?

Comment: To remove the warning is enough not to use key in the child component :)

Comment: Don't use `this.props.key` to get rid of the warning

Comment: Remove the key attribute from that div

Answer (score 2):

Don't access `this.props.key`. Key is for React itself. If you need value of key *"pass it as a different prop"*. For example:

```
<AccountCard 
  key={i}
  myKey={i}
  lastTransactions = {account.lastTransactions} 
  bank={account.bank} 
  number={account.number} 
  id={account.id} 
 />
```

`Key` is for React, `myKey` is for you to access with `this.props.myKey`. See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are correct, I'd like to add an alternative solution.

Instead of passing the key down via some arbitrary prop, you can provide a key directly by wraping a `div` around each `AccountCard`. Like so:

```
this.state.accounts.map(function(account, i){
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <AccountCard 
        lastTransactions = {account.lastTransactions} 
        bank={account.bank} 
        number={account.number} 
        id={account.id} 
      />
    </div>
  )
})
```

---

**OR**, use [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) if you are using React v16.2 or later:

```
this.state.accounts.map(function(account, i){
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={i}>
      <AccountCard 
        lastTransactions = {account.lastTransactions} 
        bank={account.bank} 
        number={account.number} 
        id={account.id} 
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
})
```

Using [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) will not add any unnecessary elements to the DOM (like the `div` in the first example). You can also use the `<>` and `</>` shorthand syntax if you prefer.